# EXIM relay works for SMTP connection but not for sendmail commands

Tags: sendmail, exim

I configured a new exim installation to forward every messages to an external SMTP provider.
I can test from smtp connections that the relay works well.

Now I need to use sendmail (or similar exim command) to send email using the same routing.

From the main.log for the CLI Command I can read the user and the hostname in this way (obfuscated from real addresses):

```
exim -v -f [realusername@realdomain] [rcpt-to@example.com] < /tmp/message
1egtHK-0002Eb-46 <= user@hostname.localdomain U=ogio P=local S=357 M8S=0 from <user@hostname.localdomain> for [rcpt-to@example.com]
```

As exim are not using the [realusername@realdomain] but the system user and hostname, the relay says it cannot delivery the message.
What is wrong in the command line?
The same behaviour with sendmail (but it is an exim alias).

Can someone help me understanding why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.
The user used to send email was not trusted, as explained in the exim man page, in the -f option.

So I added the row in the exim.conf:

```
trusted_users = [local user to be trusted]
```

This solved my issue.
Hope this can help someone else.